# How to select from table where foreign key column is known

Tags: mysql, sql

table foo_bar

```
id | name | parent(foreign key)
------------------
1  | foo  | null
2  | bar  | 1
3  | sql  | 1
```

How to select rows if the foreign key column is known?
For example i want to select all rows where the parent name is 'foo' and it should output bar and sql row

Answer (score 1):

You need a self join:

```
select f1.*
from foo_bar f1 inner join foo_bar f2
on f1.parent = f2.id
where f2.name = 'foo'
```

or you can get the id of the parent first and use it in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from foo_bar
where parent = (select id from foo_bar where name = 'foo')
```

Comment: I would avoid the second form with MySQL, it often implements it very sub-optimally.

Comment: The join is the first choice. But for a relatively small table the second query will do.

Comment: The problem is that small tables eventually grow into large tables, and a simple query gets *very* slow.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The following with `exists` might be a more performant alternative to @forpas' good answer :

```
select * 
  from foo_bar f1
 where exists (select 1 
                 from foo_bar f2 
                where f2.name = 'foo' 
                  and f2.id = f1.parent
               )
```